# Как конвертировать PyQt5.QtGui.QImage в PIL.Image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, pillow

Как конвертировать `PyQt5.QtGui.QImage` в `PIL.Image`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У `PIL` есть для этого полезная функция [ImageQt.fromqimage](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/baaa298e00dd4b2ab39c264c8c8b15cd011b8b32/src/PIL/ImageQt.py#L60). Причем, она работает для `QImage` и `QPixmap`

Установка:

```
pip install pillow
pip install pyqt5
```

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/964c5dd11f799092eb07917c3b866dac0cc3527e/pil_pillow__examples/qimage_qpixmap__to__pil_image/main.py):

```
from PIL import ImageQt
from PyQt5.Qt import QImage, QPixmap, QApplication

image_file = "input.jpg"

app = QApplication([])

img_image = QImage(image_file)
pix_image = QPixmap(image_file)

pil_img_image = ImageQt.fromqimage(img_image)
pil_img_image.show()

pil_pix_image = ImageQt.fromqimage(pix_image)
pil_pix_image.show()
```